# tooltip causing deadlock in swing/netbeans-rcp

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-platform, openide

I have a netbeans platform based app. 
It has an outlineview, with several columns. when i have my app maximised. and hover over the right most column to display the tooltip (that has to be adjusted due to end of screen). the application hangs (or rather, eventqueue is blocked).  Sometimes it starts running again after a few seconds, but mostly i have to kill the application.

Its in Container.getTreeLock its deadlocked. 
It is only when the window is maximised
I don't have any computation for the string that is displayed.
I have tried several java6update versions
I have tried upgrading netbeans platform
None of my code is in the stacktrace when it is deadlocked.

I'm out of ideas, does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing your code, you may not be following the EDT rule which essentially says any interaction with the GUI must be done on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Here are a couple of pointers that may be useful:

- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html
- http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-main-thread.html
- http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=204

Comment: I would love to show my code, but since i dont know where the problem is, its hard to show anything.
I dont think its that there is something that should be on the EDT that isnt, i think its more likely that there is to much on the EDT. 
All that i know (or atleast al that im aware of) i do, is to overide a method in netbeans property classes, to tell it what to write in the tooltip. al that method does is to return a string...